# Highcharts pointer cursor doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I'm working with highcharts and my charts work just fine, except for the legend. I'm facing two problems with the legend: a) I'm trying to set the cursor (when hovering over a legend item) to pointer style and it just won't show as a pointer for some reason, and b) If I want to hide any one data entry from the chart, I have to click on the color key of that item in the legend; clicking on the text name of that entry does not work. Like: in the attached fiddle, if I want to hide out the 'Triangle' data, clicking on 'Triangle' does not work. I have to click on the blue circle next to it. How can I fix this? I'm using this code in my chart.legend:

```
legend: {
        width: 0,
        enabled: true,
        itemStyle: {
                'cursor': 'pointer'
            }
    }
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/adway/gv7a6ngg/13/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 232 of your css:

```
text {
 pointer-events: none;
}
```

Kill it with fire